# Dynamically Resize Text Based on Container Width

Tags: javascript, jquery, font-size, responsive-design

I'm working on a responsive design and I have some display `<h3>` tags that I would like to scale down when the width of the browser window is reduced.

The initial setup, based on a width of 960px:

1. The body font-size is set to 14px
2. The font-size of the h3 tag is 40px
3. The width of the containing div is 230px

So here's what I worked out for the javascript/jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var containerSize = $('.container').width();
    var textPercentage = 0.17391304347826086956521739130435; /* 40/230 */
    var textRatio = containerSize * textPercentage;
    var textEms = textRatio / 14;

    $('.container h3').css(fontSize,textEms+"em");
});
```

My javscript skills are obviously quite limited, so I was hoping you could help me get this all purdy and working right. I think the `$(window).resize` function is the wrong event to use, since the text should resize automatically on page load, not just on window resize.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Note: I don't want the text to stretch to the edges of the containers, which is why I'm not using FitText.js or BigText.js.

Comment: You should be able to use css media queries for this, no need to use js

Comment: @Jasper and ShankarSangoli both gave answers, but I would add a note that you might want to consider throttling how often the resize event handler is executed. Refer to http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ or http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#throttle

Comment: @elclanrs Media Queries only allow me to resize text based on a specific window width. I want my text to _automatically_ resize in response to the width of the container.

Comment: @jessegavin Can you explain what that plugin does exactly? I assume it has something to do with keeping the script from running continuously, but I don't understand the technical jargon. Thanks!

Comment: @pixelcook the article does a much better job than I would at explaining it.

Comment: @jessegavin That article uses a lot of technical jargon I'm unfamiliar with (jQuery n00b). I was hoping you might be able to break it down in plain English?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`window.resize` is the correct event but it doesn't fire on page-load. You can however just add `.trigger('resize')` to your code to make it fire on page-load:

```
$(window).bind('resize', function(){
    var containerSize  = $('.container').width(),
        textPercentage = 0.17391304347826086956521739130435, /* 40/230 */
        textRatio      = containerSize * textPercentage,
        textEms        = textRatio / 14;

    $('.container h3').css(fontSize, textEms+"em");
}).trigger('resize');
```

You are going to want to run this code after `document.ready` to make sure the width you are getting for the container is correct. You could also place this code at the bottom of your HTML document (which you should do with or without the `document.ready` event handler) which will make sure the elements are available when you run this code:

```
//wait for `document.ready` to fire
$(function () {

    //cache the .container and H3 elements
    var $container = $('.container'),
        $h3        = $container.find('h3');

    //bind event handler to `window.resize`
    $(window).bind('resize', function(){

        //get the width of the container
        var containerSize  = $container.width(),
            textPercentage = 0.17391304347826086956521739130435, /* 40/230 */
            textRatio      = containerSize * textPercentage,
            textEms        = textRatio / 14;

        $h3.css('fontSize', textEms+"em");
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Notice that I cached the `H3` element(s) so it/then don't have to be selected every `resize` event, because when you actually re-size your browser there are tons of these events that fire.

Comment: Hi Jasper, thank you so much for responding!

I have a question about "waiting for `document.ready` to fire". I don't quite understand what that means, can you explain or link me to an article that explains? Thanks!

Comment: I think the guys at jQuery can explain it a bit better: http://api.jquery.com/ready/. `The handler passed to .ready() is guaranteed to be executed after the DOM is ready, so this is usually the best place to attach all other event handlers and run other jQuery code.`. Basically when you put your code inside a `document.ready` event handler you will ensure that the elements you want to manipulate will be available to do so (if you for instance put your JS code in the head of the document w/o a `document.ready` event handler you won't be able to select elements in the body tag.

Comment: It is my understanding that placing the link to your script at the bottom of the page makes that unnecessary, since the DOM loads before the script. Is that correct?

Comment: Pretty much, that's what I do. Your code will be able to execute sooner if it's not inside a `document.ready` event handler. You can see when this event fires by watching the Network tab of your Developer Tools; you can also see when `window.load` fires. You can save seconds sometimes when not using a `document.ready` event handler.

Comment: Sweet. Jasper, this is great - thank you for your excellent answer, my responsive design thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var containerSize = $('.container').width();
    var textPercentage = 0.17391304347826086956521739130435; /* 40/230 */
    var textRatio = containerSize * textPercentage;
    var textEms = textRatio / 14;

    //fontSize should be enclosed in quotes
    $('.container h3').css('fontSize', textEms+"em");
})
.resize();//Triggers the resize on page load to set the font size
```

Answer (score 0):

For people who find this by googling something like 'responsive font size', this might be of help:

https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js

It is a jQuery plugin that sets a font-size based on it's container's width. It also has some options to get the desired results.

PS: Of course it also scales your text when the window gets resized.