# jQuery Resizing Text to window

Tags: jquery, fonts, resize

I am using `em` units for my text, however, it doesn't seem to work.  In huge width screen resolutions, the text is not wide/big enough to fill the screen, in small screen resolutions, it wraps.  How can I control this?

Basically, it would be nice if I could control the size of the text based on the actual windows size.  So that, if the window gets resized down and/or up, the text accomodates for it, and the layout should look the same at all times (in all browser screen widths).

How can I do this?  Have been playing with the jQuery resize event, but not sure how I can use it for my purpose.  Maybe someone can get me started in the right direction here?

The following is an example of a jsFiddle that does this:  http://jsfiddle.net/vqbCL/2/

But, that is for table elements, I'm not using any table elements.  Trying for a fluid layout.  So, would be nice if I could incorporate that technique on font sizes of all elements on the page.

Here is the code I am using in a feeble attempt at trying to do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).bind("resize", function(){
        var containerSize  = $("body").width(),
            bodyFontSize = $("body").css("font-size");
            textPercentage = parseInt(bodyFontSize.substring(0, bodyFontSize.length - 2)) / $("body").width(),
            textRatio      = containerSize * textPercentage,
            textEms        = textRatio / parseInt(bodyFontSize.substring(0, bodyFontSize.length - 2));
            alert("Text Percentage = " + textPercentage + "\nTextRatio = " + textRatio + "\nNew EM font-size = " + textEms);

        $('body').css('fontSize', textEms+'em');
    }).trigger("resize");
});
```

What is happening here is this:

```
containerSize = 974 (might be different for you depending on your browser width).
bodyFontSize = 16px
textPercentage = 16/974 = 0.01642710472279261
textRatio = 974 * 0.01642710472279261 = 16
textEm = 16 / 16 = 1em;
```

Need to determine how to get the proper textRatio and get the proper textEm from that.

*** Updated to newest code above ***

You can see me trying to implement this here:  http://dream-portal.net/Test/index.html

Basically, the Text Ratio (16 pixels) and the EM Font-Size is always 1em (they are always the same), however, the only thing that changes here is the `Text Percentage` on window resize.  But the font-size is always 1em and Text Ratio always = 16 (as in 16 pixels, which is the `body.css("font-size")` value.  There must be some sort of flaw in the formula for calculating this somewhere.

Comment: maybe it can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218081/dynamically-resize-text-based-on-container-width

Comment: Not sure how to use that to be able to affect all text on the page.  Because that example is for an `h3` tag only.

Comment: try to change h3 tag to body

Comment: What about the `containerSize` and the `textPercentage` variables?

Comment: @la_thief - Updated answer with the code from that question's answer, but doesn't work for me.

Comment: I don't think that your `textPercentage` and `textEms` will have a number value. Try to give it a number manually and try to change your `containerSize` value to `$('body').width()`

Comment: This is not working.  You can see it here:  http://dream-portal.net/Test/index.html  I made the changes, I don't have a clue what they are doing, seems nothing.  No errors though, so don't know what else to try.

Comment: your `textEms` still have `$("body").css("font-size")` value and it will not produce a number value because it has `px` in the end of size

Comment: I used `substring` and `parseInt` to get rid of the px, and convert it to an integer value.  Still not working:  You can visit the page, and see in the alert box, the New EM size is always `1em`  The textPercentage values change, but the end result is always the same.

Comment: I updated my question with the newest code that I'm using, so you can see it and maybe pinpoint the problem.  I'm so close to getting this working, but it's like I'm an inch away from it...

Comment: The `textRatio` and `textEms` are always the same no matter what `textPercentage` is.

Comment: your `textPercentage` is changed when browser size changed. Don't divide with `$("body").width()`. Try to give a specific number.

Comment: @la_thief - What number should I give it exactly?

Comment: OMG, Thank You, problem is solved!