# How do I bootstrap the text in php/html?

Tags: php, html, css

I wanted to ask a question about, how I can bootstrap a html tag `p` when the browser is being dragged horizontally left/right. I want my text to be following the parents size.. I have an example code in php here..

my code :

```
<?php
    include('db.php');
    $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_list");
    if($r)
    {
        echo "<div class='ui-content' data-filter='true'>";                
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r))
        {
             echo "<div data-role='collapsible'>";
             echo "<h1>".$row['rec_name']."</h1>";
             echo "</br>";
             echo "<p class='fix' align='justify'>".$row['rec_desc']."</p>";
             echo "</div>";
        }
            echo "</div>";
    }
    else
    {
        mysql_error();
    }
?>
```

my **rec_desc** have 500 texts.. i want it to be responsive and in the parent when the browser is being resized.. thanks..

Comment: Bootstrap it? Does that mean something when used as a verb that I'm not aware of?

Comment: what does dragging the browser window around have to do with text size being displayed in the window? dragging a window around would only resize the text if you're resizing the window and have some scaling code/css in there.

Comment: By bootstrapping it do you actually mean make it responsive to the width of the browser window??

Comment: If you're looking to dynamically resize text, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218081/dynamically-resize-text-based-on-container-width) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5358183/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-scale-text-size-based-on-browser-width).

Comment: I just want it to be responsive and inside the parent when the browser is being resized..